# Excel Doc after c# modifications: Ctrl + DownArrow is not working properly

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, isnullorempty

guys!

After I create Excel document in my c# application the Ctrl+DownArrow combination doesn't work properly.
It goes to the last row in the current column. So looks like it means all sheet as one data region WITHOUT empty cells.

so I guess empty cells in my excel sheet aren't empty for Excel.

How to figure it out?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a macro of what you want to happen. Then look at the macro code which is based off of interops calls. See if it sheds a light on your issue and how to resolve.

Comment: Problem was not solved and I left it as is for now.. Thank you for you comments!

Answer (score 0):

Just filter out the "Blanks" Ctrl+Down Arrow and all the blank cells would be selected, now press delete (From key board).
DONE. Now you can jump between entries with Ctrl+Down Arrow.